# Representing everywhere a camera can see as a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, computer-science

I'm learning about Computer Graphics and there is one point really puzzling me.

I understand that vertices (vectors) represent points in space and that transformation matrices represent changes that could be made to said vertices.

However, when it comes to defining what is visible to a camera, I don't understand how a single matrix can represent the entire space in view.

For example, suppose I have a cube and a cylinder somewhere in 3D space, how can I create a camera that "sees" them? How can I describe a matrix that fits the entire frustum?

I am finding this concept incredibly confusing.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you wouldn't consider the concept of a camera as you describe it as an object inside you matrix. There are obviously many ways to achieve a camera, but let me vaguely describe one way. This isn't meant to be technically correct, but give you somewhat of an idea of how it can work.

Think of it more like the following:

Your (model view) matrix is representing your world state. Your "camera" is just looking at that matrix from a fixed position. Instead of moving the camera, you move the entire world (matrix).

You don't rotate the camera left, you rotate your world right.

You don't move your camera forward, you move your world backward.

This way you could define a pane like z=0 as your cameras position and not consider anything with z>0 ("behind the camera") as visible. Starting from there you could span up your frustrum into the distance (up to some arbitrary "max view distance") to determine what would be visible.

So, no matter what the camera sees, it all stays in your world matrix. Your camera is more of an applied manipulation to your world state, in OpenGL stored in a different matrix. 
I would recommend on reading up on the difference between Model Matrix and View Matrix in OpenGL, there are some nice visual explanations.

Comment: Are you sure you don't move your camera? Then why does the camera have position, look at, and up vectors if they never need to be changed? Why not just default it to a certain point and move the world around that point?

Comment: Well, you do move the camera, but in another sense. The camera isn't an object stored in the world matrix. The "camera" is a seperate view matrix. If you apply movement to your camera this is equivalent to applying that matrix manipulation to your view matrix. This allows to store all camera movements in the view matrix and just apply it to the world matrix when rendering. By doing that you can also have multiple cameras in different position and swap them out, simply by choosing which view matrix to apply to your world matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix is only *part* of the representation of what the camera can see. It's defined by two things: the matrix and a cone (or, more precisely, a frustrum). The frustrum typically has four parameters (angular width, angular height, near clipping plane, far clipping plane).

You're right that one way to see the matrix action is that it transforms vertices. Another way to see it is to think about all of the vertices simultaneously and say that the matrix transforms *space* (while the camera remains fixed, so the effect is to move things in and out of the frustrum). And a third way to think about it is that it does the inverse of that transformation *only on the camera* (so space stays fixed and the camera moves).

So if you want the camera to see an object you need to find a transformation which moves that object into the frustrum, or alternatively a transformation which moves the camera such that the object is in the frustrum.

Comment: Thanks Peter. So to define a view space, you need more than just a matrix, correct? It sounds like you must define the parameters of the frustum. If so, determining if something is within view of the camera is more complicated that just dealing with matrix transformations. Can you give me an example of how you would do so?

Comment: @Imray, the frustrum is bounded by 6 planes. Testing which side of a plane a point is on comes down to looking at the sign of a dot product. (E.g. if the plane is defined by a point $P$ in the plane and its normal $N$ then you can test which side a point $Q$ is by looking at the sign of $(Q-P).N$). It wouldn't surprise me, though, if actual implementations take a different approach. If you transform the world such that your camera is positioned at the origin and looks along the $z$-axis, with the up vector pointing along the $y$-axis, then (cont)

Comment: you can test a point $Q=(x_Q, y_Q, z_Q)$ against the near and far planes by simply comparing $z_Q$ to the near and far clipping distances; you can clip against the side planes by comparing $x_Q / z_Q$ to $\pm\tan (\theta_w/2)$ where $\theta_w$ is the angular width; and you can clip against the top and bottom planes by comparing $y_Q / z_Q$ to $\pm\tan (\theta_h/2)$ where $\theta_h$ is the angular height.